# How to stop MATLAB from rounding extremely small values to 0?

Tags: matlab

I have a code in MATLAB which works with very small numbers, for example, I have values that are on the order of 10^{-25}, however when MATLAB does the calculations, the values themselves are rounded to 0. Note, I am not referring to `format` to display these extra decimals, but rather the number itself is changed to 0. I think the reason is because MATLAB, by default, uses up to 15 digits after the decimal point for its calculations. How can I change this so that numbers that are very very small are retained as they are in the calculations?

EDIT:

My code is the following:

```
clc;
clear;

format long;

% Import data
P = xlsread('Data.xlsx', 'P');
d = xlsread('Data.xlsx', 'd');
CM = xlsread('Data.xlsx', 'Cov');


Original_PD = P;                       %Store original PD
LM_rows = size(P,1)+1;                           %Expected LM rows
LM_columns = size(P,2);                 %Expected LM columns
LM_FINAL = zeros(LM_rows,LM_columns);    %Dimensions of LM_FINAL

for ii = 1:size(P,2)

P = Original_PD(:,ii);
% c1, c2, ..., cn, c0, f
interval = cell(size(P,1)+2,1);

for i = 1:size(P,1)
    interval{i,1} = NaN(size(P,1),2);
    interval{i,1}(:,1) = -Inf;
    interval{i,1}(:,2) = d;

    interval{i,1}(i,1) = d(i,1);
    interval{i,1}(i,2) = Inf;
end
interval{i+1,1} = [-Inf*ones(size(P,1),1) d];
interval{i+2,1} = [d Inf*ones(size(P,1),1)];

c = NaN(size(interval,1),1);
for i = 1:size(c,1)
    c(i,1) = mvncdf(interval{i,1}(:,1),interval{i,1}(:,2),0,CM);
end

c0 = c(size(P,1)+1,1);
f = c(size(P,1)+2,1);
c = c(1:size(P,1),:);
b0 = exp(1);
b = exp(1)*P;

syms x;

eqn = f*x;
for i = 1:size(P,1)
    eqn = eqn*(c0/c(i,1)*x + (b(i,1)-b0)/c(i,1));
end

eqn = c0*x^(size(P,1)+1) + eqn - b0*x^size(P,1);

x0 = solve(eqn);
x0 = double(x0);

for i = 1:size(x0)
    id(i,1) = isreal(x0(i,1));
end

x0 = x0(id,:);
x0 = x0(x0 > 0,:);

clear x;

for i = 1:size(P,1)
    x(i,:) = (b(i,1) - b0)./(c(i,1)*x0) + c0/c(i,1);
end

% x = [x0 x1 ... xn]
x = [x0'; x];
x = x(:,sum(x <= 0,1) == 0);

% lamda
lamda = -log(x);
LM_FINAL(:,ii) = lamda;
end
```

The problem is in this step:

```
 for i = 1:size(P,1)
        x(i,:) = (b(i,1) - b0)./(c(i,1)*x0) + c0/c(i,1);
end
```

where the "difference" gets very close to 0. How can I stop this rounding from occurring at this step?

For example, when i = 10, I have the following values:

```
b_10 = 0.006639735483297
b_0 = 2.71828182845904
c_10 = 0.000190641848119641
c_0 = 0.356210110252579
x_0 = 7.61247930625269
```

After doing the calculations we get: -1868.47805854794 + 1868.47805854794  which yields a difference of -2.27373675443232E-12, that gets rounded to 0 by MATLAB.

EDIT 2:

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtergvvy9mfqkfd/data.xlsx) is my data file which is used for the code. After you run the code (should take about a minute and half to finish running), row `11` in the variable `x` shows 0 (even after double clicking to check it's real value), when it shouldn't.

Comment: Matlab doesn't change those small _numbers_ to 0. Try typing for example `x = 10^-60` and check that `x` has the correct value. However, small _differences_ do get rounded to 0: for example, `x = 1+10^-25` gives `1`, because of the reason you point out.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem actually, I have edited my original post with my code, any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Scale the numbers so that they are larger. EG use numerator = (b(i,1) - b0)./b0

Comment: This is a common problem in numerical computation called [machine precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Approximation_using_MATLAB) EG you can see how accurate a double (AKA IEEE floating point decimal) is by calling MATLAB builtin [`eps()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). The general solution is to scale your numbers so that they are all between 0 and 1, however this is not possible if your problem is very stiff. In that situation, use [higher precision decimals see below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21940724/1020470).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I also get numbers that are outside 0 and 1, while sometimes they become super small. I'm quite new to MATLAB, can you show me how to fix my code in the context of your answer?

Comment: when do the numbers get rounded by MATLAB, I ran your numbers and MATLAB gives me `2.501110429875553e-12`, which is within MATLAB precision of `eps() = 2.220446049250313e-16`. Are you writing out to a file? It may be the precision you are using to write files with, which is specified differently depending on which tool you use, but is generally specified by a formatter `%25e` which means output scientific notation using up to 25 characters.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class). I just saw, somebody has suggested the same thing.

Comment: @MarkMikofski, That's very weird, please refer to my initial post, I've made another edit and attached my data file used for the code. After you run it, please check variable x, row 11, which outputs 0 (as it's true value), when it shouldn't be.

Comment: (1) MATLAB 2013a `mvncdf()` limits size to 25, so I truncated `data.xlsx` which was 58x58. (2) my x(11) = 0.003250645475873. (3) none of the values were zero. (4) maybe by truncating data, I am altering results? What version are you using?

Comment: Ah yes, truncating data will certainly change results. I removed the limiter on `mvncdf()`, simply change the 25 to (say) 60, will allow the code to run.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're having is because the [IEEE standard for floating points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) can't distinguish your numbers from zero because they don't utilize sufficient bits.

Have a look at John D'Errico's [Big Decimal Class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class) and [Variable Precision Integer Arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic). Another option would be to use the [Big Integer Class from Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) but that might be more challenging if you are unfamiliar with using [Java and othe rexternal libraries in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/external-interfaces.html).

Can you give an example of the calculations in which you are using 1e-25 and getting zero? Here's what I get for a floating point called `small_num` and one of John's high-precision-floats called `small_hpf` when assigning them and multiplying by `pi`.

```
>> small_num = 1e-25

small_num =

   1.0000e-25

>> small_hpf = hpf(1e-25)
small_hpf =
1.000000000000000038494869749191839081371989361591338301396127644e-25
>> small_num * pi

ans =

   3.1416e-25

>> small_hpf * pi
ans =
3.141592653589793236933163473501228686498684350685747717239459106e-25
```